# Htaccess file redirect to certain web page according to requested domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, request

I will put it as simple as I can. I really need your help, so one of the domains let's say **example1.com** is set to point to **real_domain.com**, basically what happens is when you type into your browser **example1.com** it will redirect you to **real_domain.com**.

So basically I need and if that is even possible. I would like to write **htaccess** file on the  **real_domain.com** so that according to different **requested URL** points it to certain subdomain, let say if you type in your browser **example1.com** it should bring you to **real_domain.com/es**.

My question is if that is even possible to do and if so HOW TO DO IT, I tried something like this but it didn't happen:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.real_domain.com/es [L,R=301]
```

Is that even a right approach? Can this be done, if so, every help is very much appreciated. Sorry if the topic is already somewhere I tried it but didn't found it.

P.S. I don't have access to **example.com** htaccess file it just redirected to **real_domain.com** I assume with **moniker.com**.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the .htaccess file on real_domain.com should evaluate where the request is coming from, so I'd give it a shot with testing against the "referer" header in the HTTP Request:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.real_domain.com/es [L,R=301]
```

I'd consider catching `www.example.com`, too.